# O método não funciona fora da classe no JS

Tags: javascript

Fiz uma classe e criei os métodos dentro dela normalmente mas quando coloco método semelhante fora da classe eles não funcionam como esperado, a execução do if ocorre normalmente, mas o valor que deveria ser retirado da propriedade não é retirado

```js
class Conta {
    constructor(saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo
    }

    deposito(valor){
        if(valor>100){
            this.saldo += valor
        } else {
            console.log('valor inferior ao permitido')
        }
    }
}

Conta.prototype.saque = (valor) => {
    if(valor<100){
        this.saldo -= valor
    } else {
        console.log('valor maior do que o permitido')
    }
}

let fulano = new Conta (1000)

fulano.deposito(90)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.deposito(110)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.saque(90)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.saque(110)
console.log(fulano)
```

Comment: Funções Arrow não possuem valor vinculado ao `this`(objeto que chama a função). Onde está `Conta.prototype.saque = (valor) => {` substitua por `Conta.prototype.saque = function (valor) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente, quando vc trabalha com classes, vc não deveria alterar o `prototype` da forma como vc fez, pois isto só deixaria o código mais confuso.

De qualquer forma, seu raciocionio está correto e vc só errou em um detalhe:

Quando vc usa *arrow functions* o `this` funciona de forma diferente. No seu caso, ele se refere ao objeto global e não à sua instância de `Conta`.

Para funcionar como vc espera, troque por uma função anônima comum. Assim:

```js
Conta.prototype.saque = function (valor) {
  if (valor < 100) {
    this.saldo -= valor;
  } else {
    console.log('valor maior do que o permitido');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

O [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) é usado para extender um objeto e não uma classe:

> Protótipos são o mecanismo pelo qual objetos JavaScript herdam
> recursos uns dos outros

Usamos o `prototype` quando declaramos objetos com `functions` por exemplo, não como classes. Uma classe é fechada, para extendê-la é preciso herdá-la.

Há ai uma confusão misturando dois conceitos...

Podemos declarar um objeto assim:

```js
let Conta = function(saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;

    this.deposito = (valor) => {
        if(valor>100){
            this.saldo += valor
        } else {
            console.log('valor inferior ao permitido')
        }
    }
}

Conta.prototype.saque = function (valor) {
    if(valor<100){
        this.saldo -= valor
    } else {
        console.log('valor maior do que o permitido')
    }
}

let fulano = new Conta (1000)

fulano.deposito(90)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.deposito(110)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.saque(90)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.saque(110)
console.log(fulano)
```

Dessa forma, `prototype` está extendendo o objeto.
Já para uma classe, `prototype` não vai funcionar da mesma forma, nesse caso deve adicionar o método diretamente na class, ou extender a classe e usar o objeto extendido:

```js
class Conta {
    constructor(saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo
    }

    deposito(valor){
        if(valor>100){
            this.saldo += valor
        } else {
            console.log('valor inferior ao permitido')
        }
    }
    
    saque = (valor) => {
       if(valor<100){
           this.saldo -= valor
       } else {
           console.log('valor maior do que o permitido')
       }
    }
}

let fulano = new Conta (1000)

fulano.deposito(90)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.deposito(110)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.saque(90)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.saque(110)
console.log(fulano)
```

E aqui extendendo a classe Conta:

```js
class Conta {
    constructor(saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo
    }

    deposito(valor){
        if(valor>100){
            this.saldo += valor
        } else {
            console.log('valor inferior ao permitido')
        }
    }
}


class Conta2 extends Conta {
  constructor(saldo) {
    super(saldo)
  }
  
  saque(valor)  {
       if(valor<100){
           this.saldo -= valor
       } else {
           console.log('valor maior do que o permitido')
       }
    }
}

let fulano = new Conta2 (1000)

fulano.deposito(90)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.deposito(110)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.saque(90)
console.log(fulano)

fulano.saque(110)
console.log(fulano)
```

Comment: Está confusa essa explicação. Não existe de facto classe em javascript, quando faz `let fulano = new Conta()` na verdade está fazendo `let fulano = Object.create(Conta)`

Comment: Uma classe em JavaScript, por debaixo dos panos, continua sendo uma função. Vc pode atestar isto usando `typeof Conta`. E, sendo uma função, ela também tem a propriedade `prototype`, q pode ser usada para estendê-la normalmente. O erro do autor da pergunta foi apenas ter usado uma _arrow function_ ao invés de uma função normal, pois isto afetou o `this`. Vale destacar que, embora ele não esteja tecnicamente errado, estender classes desta forma só torna o código desnecessáriamente complexo e ele deveria usar todas as facilidades que as classes oferecem como vc demonstrou no seu último exemplo.